# Pivoting a Pandas dataframe while deduplicating additional columns

Tags: python, pandas

Similar to the [documentation example](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), I want to pivot the following dataframe:

```
  foo extra bar  baz
0 one     x   A    1
1 one     x   B    2
2 one     x   C    3
3 two     y   A    4
4 two     y   B    5
5 two     y   C    6
```

The result should be

```
     extra A  B  C

one      x 1  2  3
two      y 4  5  6
```

Can this be done in a shorter way than

- splitting the extra column off before pivoting
- deduplicating it separately
- merging it back to the pivoted data?

(I expected the pivot command to be able to do this, but my tries failed.)

Here's the code for the dataframe to play with it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one','one','one','two','two','two'],
                   'extra': ['x','x','x','y','y','y'],
                   'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'baz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set_index` and `unstack`

```
In [2087]: df.set_index(['foo', 'extra', 'bar'])['baz'].unstack().reset_index()
Out[2087]:
bar  foo extra  A  B  C
0    one     x  1  2  3
1    two     y  4  5  6
```

Comment: Nice! To reach the required result, a final `.set_index('foo')` has to be added. In case of duplicate foo/bar pairs, this preserves the `pivot`command's error.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pivot_table`, `pivot` only accepts one column as *index*, *column* and *value* while `pivot_table` can accept multiple columns:

```
df.pivot_table('baz', ['foo', 'extra'], 'bar').reset_index()

#bar    foo extra   A   B   C
#  0    one     x   1   2   3
#  1    two     y   4   5   6
```

Comment: Note that this has different behavior for duplicate foo/bar pairs: it aggregates the baz values instead of giving an error.